# Rails conventions: Garb model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, conventions, garb-gem

I'm using the [Garb gem](https://github.com/Sija/garb) to access Google Analytics data for my site. I've created the model that extends Garb::Model, but I can't find any information on Rails conventions for which directory  should contain such a table-less model; is it just app/models/? or lib/? Is there a way I should mark this model to indicate that its table-less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure it's too late now, but for future reference I've always just seen it put in `app/models`. It's still a model! ActiveRecord goodness is just an implementation detail.

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing, but thanks for answering for the sake of completeness!